# underscore template vs javascript html

Tags: templates, underscore.js

For my medialibrary I've been using the Underscore javascript library to append JSON data with the `_.template` function. All media items are loaded like that so I can filter the data later on with a search function. That's what it's basicly ment for right?

But I've also used it for other items like: buttons, attachments, etc.
The data is created on the fly in javascript when I select media items. After a click on the Insert button Underscore appends the small snippets.

Is that a little to much? So should I actualy just use HTML strings inside the javascript for that? Now I have 7 Underscore templates that are only small snippets for user actions that don't realy NEED Underscore templating....

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of templates (underscore/mustache.. etc) so i might be a little bias. Your alternative is to have a js string and then append things to it, thats very archaic. Or to have jquery build you the structure, thats very hard on the eyes -- at least on mine.

this to me would always be better:

```
<div class="<%= classType %>">
    <label id="<%= id %>"><%= name %></label>
    <input name="<%= name %>" id="<%= id %>" value="<%= value %>">
</div>
```

than this:

```
var template = ['<div class="', classType, '"><label id="', id, '">', name, '</label><input name="', name, '" id="', id, '" value="', value, '"></div>'].join('')
// or god forbid!!!
var template = '<div class="' + classType + '"><label id="' + id + '">' + name + '</label>'<input name="' + name + '" id="' + id + '" value="' + value + '"></div>';
```

or this:

```
// please dont ever do this, i know when you write it it makes a lot
// of sense, but trust me, when you come back a month later... no it doesnt
$('<div>').addClass(classType).append(
    $('<label>').attr('id', id).html(name)
).append(
    $('<input>').attr({'name': name, 'id': id, 'value': value})
)
```

If you have something that repeats more than once i would say, sure, add a template. The problem with the last two examples is that your project will inevitably grow, and you'll find yourself copy and pasting it "just one more time" to satisfy a requirement that you thing is "just this once".. never happens. My entire professional career is plagued with "this will only be used once" code. -- now im just rambling.

Yes. Use templates! The readability is reason enough. It will save you SOOO much time debugging.